# Pandas read_html producing empty df with tuple column names

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tuples

I want to retrieve the tables on the following website and store them in a pandas dataframe: https://www.acf.hhs.gov/orr/resource/ffy-2012-13-state-of-colorado-orr-funded-programs

However, the third table on the page returns an empty dataframe with all the table's data stored in tuples as the column headers:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Service Providers, State of Colorado), (Cuban - Haitian Program, $0), (Refugee Preventive Health Program, $150,000.00), (Refugee School Impact, $450,000), (Services to Older Refugees Program, $0), (Targeted Assistance - Discretionary, $0), (Total FY, $600,000)]
Index: []
```

Is there a way to "flatten" the tuple headers into header + values, then append this to a dataframe made up of all four tables? My code is below -- it has worked on other similar pages but keeps breaking because of this table's formatting. Thanks!

```
funds_df = pd.DataFrame()
url = 'https://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/orr/resource/ffy-2011-12-state-of-colorado-orr-funded-programs'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
year = url.split('ffy-')[1].split('-orr')[0]
tables = page.content
df_list = pd.read_html(tables)
for df in df_list:
    df['URL'] = url
    df['YEAR'] = year
    funds_df = funds_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For this site, there's no need for `beautifulsoup` or `requests`
- [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) creates a list of `DataFrames` for each `<table>` at the URL.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.acf.hhs.gov/orr/resource/ffy-2012-13-state-of-colorado-orr-funded-programs'

# read the url
dfl = pd.read_html(url)

# see each dataframe in the list; there are 4 in this case
for i, d in enumerate(dfl):
    print(i)
    display(d)  # display worker in Jupyter, otherwise use print
    print('\n')
```

- `dfl[0]`

```py
   Service Providers Cash and Medical Assistance* Refugee Social Services Program Targeted Assistance Program       TOTAL
0  State of Colorado                   $7,140,000                      $1,896,854                    $503,424  $9,540,278
```

- `dfl[1]`

```
     WF-CMA 2         RSS     TAG-F CMA Mandatory 3       TOTAL
0  $3,309,953  $1,896,854  $503,424      $7,140,000  $9,540,278
```

- `dfl[2]`

```
   Service Providers Refugee School Impact Targeted Assistance - Discretionary Services to Older Refugees Program Refugee Preventive Health Program Cuban - Haitian Program     Total
0  State of Colorado              $430,000                                  $0                           $100,000                          $150,000                      $0  $680,000
```

- `dfl[3]`

```
  Volag                             Affiliate Name Projected ORR  MG Funding                                                                     Director
0   CWS  Ecumenical Refugee & Immigration Services                  $127,600   Ferdi Mevlani  1600 Downing St., Suite 400  Denver, CO 80218  303-860-0128
1  ECDC              ECDC African Community Center                  $308,000      Jennifer Guddiche  5250 Leetsdale Drive  Denver, CO 80246  303-399-4500
2   EMM                Ecumenical Refugee Services                  $191,400   Ferdi Mevlani  1600 Downing St., Suite 400  Denver, CO 80218  303-860-0128
3  LIRS   Lutheran Family Services Rocky Mountains                  $121,000    Floyd Preston  132 E Las Animas  Colorado Springs, CO 80903  719-314-0223
4  LIRS   Lutheran Family Services Rocky Mountains                  $365,200  James Horan  1600 Downing Street, Suite 600  Denver, CO 80218  303-980-5400
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought to use `enumerate` -- that seems to be working much better!

Comment: @cmucce01 `enumerate` is used, so I know the index of each dataframe. This only had 4 tables, but some pages have more than 30 and it becomes difficult to find the one you're looking for. `enumerate` is more of a utility.